# JavaScript draw a circle on mouse click - cordinates don't match

Tags: javascript

I'm writing a simple script where the user clicks anywhere in a canvas and there appears a circle.

The script works but not correct. Somehow the cordinates where the click event happens and the circle center don't match. Any ideas why?

Here is the code :

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
     $("#special").click(function(e){ 

        var x = e.pageX - this.offsetLeft;
        var y = e.pageY - this.offsetTop; 

        /* var c=document.getElementById("special"); */
        var ctx= this.getContext("2d"); /*c.getContext("2d");*/
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
        ctx.stroke();

        $('#status2').html(x +', '+ y); 
   }); 
})  

</script>
<body> 
    <h2 id="status2">0, 0</h2>
    <canvas style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px ridge green;" id="special">

    </canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The canvas element needs the height and width tags. It's kind of odd, especially for HTML5 notation.

Try adding this in your document ready-statement (before your canvas drawing-code) and jQuery will add them for you based on your CSS styles.

```
$('#special').attr('height', $('#special').css('height'));
$('#special').attr('width', $('#special').css('width'));
```

The plus-side of this method over using manual addition of the attribute-values is that you only need to store the dimensions once, ruling out future confusion if you would use external stylesheets;

**CSS**

```
#special {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border:1px ridge green;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<canvas id="special">Not supported</canvas>
```

[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/XtBRN/3/)

Answer (score 6):

You need to add the width and height properties to your canvas element like so: (you have it in style)

```
 <canvas width="500px" height="500px" style="width: 500px; height: 500px; border:1px ridge green;" id="special">
```

Check out this fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/7xQZ2/

Adding the width and height parameters will specify how many pixels your canvas should be. The style one just shows how big it should be displayed (everything on it would get stretched).