# Using jQuery to simulate mouseclick on coordinates

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas, click

I am trying to simulate a mouse click that draws something on a canvas at a specific point on load. I was looking at this post, [JavaScript draw a circle on mouse click - cordinates don't match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15639692/javascript-draw-a-circle-on-mouse-click-cordinates-dont-match), and am experimenting on the JS Fiddle provided here: http://jsfiddle.net/7xQZ2/22/

The original JS Fiddle draws circles when you click on the canvas. Would it be possible to simulate this click on load? For example, so that when the page loads, there appears a circle at (200, 200)?

```
function simulateClick(x, y) {
    $(document.elementFromPoint(x, y)).trigger('click')
 }
simulateClick(200, 200)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Create a function that draws :

```
function draw(pageX, pageY, canvas){
  var x = pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
  var y = pageY - canvas.offsetTop; 

  var ctx= canvas.getContext("2d");
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
  ctx.stroke();

  $('#status2').html(x +', '+ y); 
 }
```

And then call that function wherever you want, inside of $("#special").click() and on page load, while passing the right arguments.

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#special").click(function(e, x, y){ 
    x = x === undefined ? e.pageX - this.offsetLeft : x;
    y = y === undefined ? e.pageY - this.offsetTop : y; 

    var ctx= this.getContext("2d");
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(x, y, 10,0, 2*Math.PI);
    ctx.stroke();

    $('#status2').html(x +', '+ y); 
}); 

function simulateClick(x, y) {
    $("#special").trigger('click', [x, y])
}

simulateClick(200, 200)
```

Will do it for you by passing the x and y values through to the click handler if you have defined them

http://jsfiddle.net/7xQZ2/23/